# Why Slider Value is reset, when I use .clickable and drag on it for the first time?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple jetpack-compose slider below, with a custom thumb. I want to be aware when the thumb is clicked, hence I add the `.clickable` as shown below.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var numberValue by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(20f) }
    Column {
        val context = LocalContext.current

        Slider(
            value = numberValue,
            onValueChange = { numberValue = it },
            valueRange = 0f..50f,
            thumb = {
                Spacer( modifier = Modifier
                    .size(20.dp)
                    .clickable {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    .background(Color.Red, CircleShape)
                )
            }
        )
        Text(
            text = "Value is $numberValue",
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )

    }
}
```

However, a strange behavior seen when `.clickable` is used.

When I click on the thumb (that's all good, I got the click feedback), and when I start drag, the slider value automatically set back to 0. This is illustrated clearer on the gif below

[image]

Note:

- Just click without dragging, it's fine
- This issue happens only on the first click and drag. Subsequent click and drag works fine
- removing the `.clickable`, everything behave well. But I cannot get my click response.

I can't link the connection of .clickable and the value change. Feels like a Google's bug. But share here in case I miss anything?

If it is a Google Bug, is there any workaround that I can still get a click (on the thumb) response, without using `.clickable`?

(p/s: I tried on Jetpack Compose 1.5.4 and 1.6.0-rc02, the problem persist)

Comment: Highly suspect it's a Google's bug. Filed issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/321145564

Comment: Workaround is still desired for anyone want to help answer this and provide workaround.

Comment: By the way, anyone try to recommend using interactionsource, seems ike Google hasn't support Pressed detection on slider. I file a Stackover on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77844709/why-mutableinteractionsource-on-slider-dont-have-response-on-pressed to verify if my finding is right.

Comment: I think you can check for wheter thumb is touch or not using ```pointerInput(Unit)``` rather using ```clickable```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get a workaround that will be able to emit both Tapped and Released signal, by using pointerInput modifier attribute.

*Special thanks to Lakshank and Rohit for coming up with the workaround!*

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var numberValue by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(20f) }
    Column {
        val context = LocalContext.current

        Slider(
            value = numberValue,
            onValueChange = { numberValue = it },
            valueRange = 0f..50f,
            thumb = {
                Spacer( modifier = Modifier
                    .size(20.dp)
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        awaitPointerEventScope {
                            while (true) {
                                val event = awaitPointerEvent()
                                if (event.type == PointerEventType.Press) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "I'm tapped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show()
                                }
                                if (event.type == PointerEventType.Release) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "I'm released!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .background(Color.Red, CircleShape)
                )
            }
        )
        Text(
            text = "Value is $numberValue",
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )

    }
}
```