# Why MutableInteractionSource on slider don't have response on Pressed?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple Jetpack-Compose slider below. I want to detect when it is pressed or when it is dragged by using `MutableInteractionSource`

```
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    var numberValue by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(20f) }
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

    val thumbPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
    val thumbDragged by interactionSource.collectIsDraggedAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(thumbPressed, thumbDragged) {
        if (thumbPressed) {
            Log.d("Track", "I'm clicked")
            Toast.makeText(context, "I'm clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if (thumbDragged) {
            Log.d("Track", "I'm dragged")
            Toast.makeText(context, "I'm dragged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    Column {

        Slider(
            value = numberValue,
            onValueChange = { numberValue = it },
            valueRange = 0f..50f,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
        )
        Text(
            text = "Value is $numberValue",
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )

    }
}
```

However, only the Dragged works (the toast is shown), but not the pressed. Why? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `sliderTap` modifier, which is a private `Modifier` uses detectTapGestures in `pointerInput` `Modifier` in source code of `Slider`  does not emit any `Interaction`s.

https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Slider.kt;drc=ef8e9f60d94a9604380d3a00a18425f999fabcda;l=905

But Modifier.draggable which is a public modifier emits drag start, dragging and drag stop `Interaction`s.

### Edit

You can add a Modifier.pointerInput with different PointerInputPass for that modifier to get that event first like this. Also, since the modifier above consumes it, you can set  `requireUnconsumed = false` to get event even if it's already consumed.

```
Slider(
    modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
        awaitEachGesture {
           awaitFirstDown(
                pass = PointerEventPass.Initial,
               // This one will work too since we get event even if slider consumes it
//               requireUnconsumed = false
            )

            Toast.makeText(context, "I'm pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    },
    value = numberValue,
    onValueChange = { numberValue = it },
    valueRange = 0f..50f,
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
)
```

Comment: Thanks. If I need to detect the tab, any workaround possible?

Comment: You can copy paste source code and add emit inside that modifier. It's only one class and only one modifier you need to modify which is pointed in asnwer. I also have a custom Slider library, and i might, add this in the future.

Comment: I tried to add pointerInput into the slider modifier, can't seems to have any effect. Can you share the code, or the custom Slider library, I could check on?

Comment: Adding it won't have any effect because it already has  one with `detectTap` gestures.  detectTap calls consume on awaitFirstDown. so next one won't get event. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70847531/5457853. But you can do it by adding a custom `pointerInput` with different PointerEventPass instead of Main. My library is this one https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Colorful-Sliders

Comment: You can check edited section. It will get the gesture first before `Slider`s touch modifiers. Also you can check this answer for detailed explanation about gesture propagation direction. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76021552/5457853